# Mapping UUID in Spark Cassandra connector

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I have the following code to save RDD to cassandra:

```
 JavaRDD<UserByID> mapped = ......

CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(mapped)
.writerBuilder("mykeyspace", "user_by_id", mapToRow(UserByID.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

And `UserByID` is a normal serializable POJO with the following variable with getters and setters

```
private UUID userid;
```

Cassandra table has exactly the same names of the class UserByID variables, and userid is of type uuid in Cassandra table, I am loading data successfully from the table using the same class mapping.

```
CassandraJavaRDD<UserByID> UserByIDRDD = javaFunctions(spark)
 .cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "user_by_id", mapRowTo(UserByID.class));
```

however, when I call `saveToCassandra` function above, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task
0 in stage 227.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
in stage 227.0 (TID 12721, localhost, executor driver): 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
The value (4e22e71a-a387-4de8-baf1-0ef6e65fe33e) of the type 
(java.util.UUID) cannot be converted to 
struct<leastSignificantBits:bigint,mostSignificantBits:bigint>
```

To solve the problem I have registered UUID codec, but that didn't help, I am using `spark-cassandra-connector_2.11` version 2.4.0 and the same version for `spark-core_2.11` any suggestion?

my reference is [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md) but it has no Java UUID example, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange error - this just works fine with connector 2.4.0 & Spark 2.2.1 with following example:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test.utest (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    u uuid
);
```

[POJO class](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/UUIDData.java):

```
public class UUIDData {
    private UUID u;
    private int id;
    ...
    // getters/setters
};
```

[Spark job](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/UUIDTest.java):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("UUIDTest")
            .getOrCreate();

    CassandraJavaRDD<UUIDData> uuids = javaFunctions(spark.sparkContext())
            .cassandraTable("test", "utest", mapRowTo(UUIDData.class));

    JavaRDD<UUIDData> uuids2 = uuids.map(x -> new UUIDData(x.getId() + 10, x.getU()));

    CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(uuids2)
            .writerBuilder("test", "utest", mapToRow(UUIDData.class))
            .saveToCassandra();
}
```

I've noticed that in your code you're using functions `mapRowTo` and `mapToRow` without calling the `.class` on POJO - are you sure that your code compiled and you don't run any old version of the code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have .class already but forgot to add them here in the question as I changed the class name from what I actually have. I will give it a try anyway.