# How to handle Cassandra "duration" datatype in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a problem with loading Cassandra (Scylla) data into Apache Spark with datastacks/spark-cassandra-connector:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.cassandraTable[(String)](keyspace, table).select("url").limit(10).collect()
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: duration
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(ColumnType.scala:117)
```

I tried different Spark and spark-cassandra-connector versions with Scala and Python but without success.
I guess it because of missing duration datatype support in datastacks/spark-cassandra-connector, I checked ColumnType.scala, they have only:

```
  private[connector] val primitiveTypeMap = Map[DataType, ColumnType[_]](
    DataType.text() -> TextType,
    DataType.ascii() -> AsciiType,
    DataType.varchar() -> VarCharType,
    DataType.cint() -> IntType,
    DataType.bigint() -> BigIntType,
    DataType.smallint() -> SmallIntType,
    DataType.tinyint() -> TinyIntType,
    DataType.cfloat() -> FloatType,
    DataType.cdouble() -> DoubleType,
    DataType.cboolean() -> BooleanType,
    DataType.varint() -> VarIntType,
    DataType.decimal() -> DecimalType,
    DataType.timestamp() -> TimestampType,
    DataType.inet() -> InetType,
    DataType.uuid() -> UUIDType,
    DataType.timeuuid() -> TimeUUIDType,
    DataType.blob() -> BlobType,
    DataType.counter() -> CounterType,
    DataType.date() -> DateType,
    DataType.time() -> TimeType
  )
```

Is anybody knows how to deal with Cassandra's duration datatype in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The Spark supported [types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSupportedTypes.html) definition does not contain Duration, but they state that

> You can convert strings that conform to the CQL standard to numbers,
>   dates, addresses or UUIDs.

Also, the Java driver already has the [class Duration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/index.html?com/datastax/driver/core/Duration.html), which constructor casts the string values to `duration`. With that in mind, you should be able to create a custom Spark connector similar to the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960752/6812035).

- I'm not a Spark user, the suggestion is only based on the documentation.